# System.TypeInitializationException occurred in MassTransit.dll

Tags: c#, exception, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have been using MassTransit along with the RabbitMQ.Client NuGet packages to publish messages to my RabbitMQ Queue. This is been working great for months. All of the sudden (with no code changes), I can no longer create a ServiceBus. Here is the code I have been using for months:

```
public class RabbitBus
{
    private IServiceBus bus;

    public void Start(Action<ServiceBusConfigurator> moreInitialization)
    {
        const string host = "rabbitmq://localhost/testqueue";

        bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
        {
            x.UseRabbitMq(r =>
            {
                r.ConfigureHost(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/testqueue"), h =>
                {
                    h.SetUsername("user");
                    h.SetPassword("password");
                });
            });
            x.ReceiveFrom(host);
            moreInitialization(x);
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        bus.Dispose();
    }

    public void Publish<T>(T message)
    {
        bus.Publish(message, x => { x.SetDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.Persistent); });
    }
}
```

And then I would publish a message like this:

```
var bus = new RabbitBus();
bus.Start((x) => {});
bus.Publish("Test");
bus.Stop();
```

Like I said, this code has been perfectly fine for months. Just yesterday, I have started receiving a **System.TypeInitializationException** when creating my ServiceBus via the `ServiceBusFactory.New` call.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in MassTransit.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'MassTransit.Monitoring.ServiceBusPerformanceCounters' threw an exception.
>
> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Here is the StackTrace:

> - at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.RegQueryValueEx(SafeRegistryHandle hKey, String lpValueName, Int32[] lpReserved, Int32& lpType, Byte[] lpData, Int32& lpcbData)
>
>   - at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String name, Object defaultValue, Boolean doNotExpand, Boolean checkSecurity)
>   - at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(String name)
>   - at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.GetData(String item)
>   - at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item)
>   - at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
>   - at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String category, String counter, Boolean& categoryExists)
>   - at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String machine, String category, String counter)
>   - at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(String counterName, String categoryName, String machineName)
>   - at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(String counterName, String categoryName)
>   - at MassTransit.Monitoring.ServiceBusPerformanceCounters.b__1(RuntimePerformanceCounter counter) in d:\BuildAgent\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Monitoring\ServiceBusPerformanceCounters.cs:line 151
>   - at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext()
>   - at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   - at MassTransit.Monitoring.ServiceBusPerformanceCounters.InitiatizeCategory() in d:\BuildAgent\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Monitoring\ServiceBusPerformanceCounters.cs:line 150
>   - at MassTransit.Monitoring.ServiceBusPerformanceCounters..ctor() in d:\BuildAgent\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Monitoring\ServiceBusPerformanceCounters.cs:line 91
>   - at MassTransit.Monitoring.ServiceBusPerformanceCounters..cctor() in d:\BuildAgent\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Monitoring\ServiceBusPerformanceCounters.cs:line 30

I have been digging around StackOverflow and other sites for hours, but have made no headway. If anyone has any insight, I'd love the help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you just getting started with MassTransit? I'd highly recommend starting with v3 if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found an answer that has fixed my problem. I found the answer in the article [How to Read Performance Counters Without Administrator Privileges](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2006/09/08/how-to-read-performance-counters-without-administrator-privileges-ryan-byington/). In case of the article ever being taken down, here are the key parts:

> Windows 2003, Windows XP x64 Edition, and Vista require that the user be part of the Performance Monitor Users group to read performance counter data. Simply adding your non admin user to this group will fix this problem.
>
> Accessing counters remotely is another story though. On Windows 2003, Windows XP x64 Edition, and Vista you still must be part of the Performance Monitor Users group on the remote machine but there is a problem with the PerformanceCounter class where it tries to read some registry keys on the remote machine that a non admin users do not have access to. To give your user read access to these keys without having to be an admin on the remote machine complete the following steps on the remote machine:
>
> 1. Open the Registry Editor by going to the Start Menu and selecting Run…, then type “regedit”, and click the OK button.
> 2. Navigate to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg registry key.
> 3. Right click on the “winreg” key and select Permissions. Add users or groups to which you want to grant Read access.
> 4. Exit Registry Editor and restart Windows.

It's odd that I had to do this, especially since I am an Admin on a Windows 7 machine, but this fix has solved my problems.